# What are the effects of setting my DHCP expiration for 8 hours and my no-refresh/refresh interval to 7 days?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008, dhcp

Say I set my DHCP lease duration to be 8 hours. And leave the default DNS no-refresh interval, and refresh interval to 7 days. What kind of side-affects would I see from this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are registering your DHCP clients in DNS, then you may show stale information in DNS.

You should be careful when allowing DHCP to be registerd in DNS.  It is possible, for  DHCP clients to register using service names like `www`, `mail`, etc.  This could allow them to replace services or perform man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Windows clients attempt to update their DNS record every 24 hours and if they are assigned a different address. One exception is when a computer is reimaged, and they no longer have permission to their record. In that scenario it will not update their record until after it is scavenged (or the permissions are fixed).

The No Refresh Interval + the Refresh Interval are the *minimum* amount of time that must elapse with no update before a DNS record will be eligible for scavenging. The No Refresh Interval + the Refresh Interval are usually configured to be larger than the lease duration, because it is considered more conservative and less risky to provide clients with multiple attempts to update their DNS record registration.

A scenario where there could be duplicate registrations of the same IP address is when transient clients get an IP address and aren't seen again. When a lease expires, an IP address may be assigned to a different client.  If that is the case, it may be necessary to lower the No Refresh Interval + the Refresh Interval.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2008/03/19/dont-be-afraid-of-dns-scavenging-just-be-patient/

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfe/2011/06/03/how-dns-scavenging-and-the-dhcp-lease-duration-relate/